# How does the number of excited fermions and holes affect the chemical potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, chemical-potential

Given we know the number of states filled with excited fermions with positive energy and the number of non-filled states with negative energy, what relation does the chemical potential have to that?

Related question: [What is the chemical potential for a system of free fermions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285674/what-is-the-chemical-potential-for-a-system-of-free-fermions)

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you consider an intrinsic semiconductor or an insulator with a conduction band and a valence band in thermodynamic equilibrium at constant temperature with electrons thermally excited from the valence band occupying the conduction band so that an equal number of holes remains in the valence band. Then you can calculate the chemical potential (i.e. the Fermi level) by equating the total number of electrons in the conduction band obtained by summing over all electrons sitting at different energies in the conduction band according to the density of states and their Fermi-Dirac energy distribution probability (which has the chemical potential as a parameter) to the total number of holes in the valence band obtained in an analogous way, also with the chemical potential as a parameter. As the chemical potential in the Fermi-Dirac distributions has to be the same, an equation for the determination of the chemical potential is obtained.